# How to integrate PowerBI in symfony4

Tags: symfony, statistics, powerbi, symfony4

I want to integrate an Advanced statistics in my project symfony 4
so i decide to use PowerBI ( if you have an alternative please let me know),

my question is how to integrate it in my local project symfony4 and in relation with my database MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Untill now , there no Symfony bundle for power bi , but instead you can use :
the [adevait/power-bi](https://packagist.org/packages/adevait/power-bi)

In case you don't find  options you are looking for , you can using the native [power bi rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/)

> You need to create an account and manage it by creating your dataset etc ...

*Requirement :*

- GuzzleHttp

The point here is to create for example a service that manage calling the api :

example for authentication :

```
try {
    /** @var GuzzleHttp\Client $client **/
    $response = $client->post(
        'https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token',
        [
            "headers" => [
                "Accept" => "application/json"
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'resource'      => 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
                'client_id'     => $this->clientId,
                'client_secret' => $this->secret,
                'grant_type'    => 'password',
                'username'      => $this->username,
                'password'      => $this->password,
                'scope'         => 'openid',
            ]
        ]
    );

    $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    return $body['access_token'];
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
}
```

At this point , you need the token to call other endpoint , so you need to inject the returned token in the header of any request you send like :

```
try {
    /** @var GuzzleHttp\Client $client **/
    $client->post(
        https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/<group-id>/datasets/<dataset-id>/tables/<table-name>/rows,
        [
            'headers' => [
                "Accept"        => "application/json",
                "Authorization" => sprintf("Bearer %s", $token),
            ],
            'json'    => $data
        ]
    );

    return true;
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

Hope that help you .

Comment: really i'm don't understood

Comment: what exactly you don't understand ?

Comment: Is PowerBI not free ?

Comment: you can use the free trial here https://app.powerbi.com/signupredirect?pbi_source=web